# Postfix + Spambrella filtering

Tags: linux, email, postfix, smtp, dovecot

I've set up a Postfix + Dovecot & MySQL server which is to serve email for two domains, each with a static IP.
I have working SSL certificates for each domain, and they are installed correctly, using the .pem format.
The company I work for currently uses Spambrella for email filtering, and I'd like to continue using this service with the new server, and I have correctly configured both domains & all users with Spambrella's administration portal.

I can connect to my server using telnet/openssl, on ports 25, 465, and 587, and successfully send emails to the accounts set up on my server (for both domains).
IMAP (as well as the required ports) is also configured and works as expected.

However, whenever I try to send an email to my server through Spambrella, the email bounces.
The email seemingly bounces before it reaches my server as I am not notified of the bounce.
Initially I tried setting up the MX records for the domains as per Spambrella's specification: https://www.spambrella.com/faq/data-center-information/
I have reverted the DNS MX records for now, to minimise email downtime, and I am now testing the configuration by telnetting into Spambrella's server: <mx1-eu1.ppe-hosted.com> which is the correct server for our location.
I have even contacted Spambrella multiple times about this issue, and they have elevated it to their "senior technician team" but I am yet to hear back from them.

The email always bounces with the following response:

```
This is the PPE Hosted Dispatch mail system.

PPE Hosted tried to deliver your email message,
but was unable to do so for reasons outside our control.

We recommend contacting the person or service responsible for
looking after the recipient domain's email server directly.

The last error message we have available from the recipient's
server is included right below, along with an extract of your
email:


<user@domain>: host a1.mail.domain.localhost[correct ip] said:
    550 Relaying denied (in reply to RCPT TO command)


Reporting-MTA: dns; dispatch1-eu1.ppe-hosted.com
X-PPE-Hosted-ESMTP-Server-Queue-ID: 1578A20052
X-PPE-Hosted-ESMTP-Server-Sender: rfc822; myemail@mydomain
Arrival-Date: Fri, 18 Sep 2020 11:50:00 +0000 (UTC)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; user@domain
Original-Recipient: rfc822; user@domain
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; a1.mail.domain.localhost
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 Relaying denied


Return-Path: <myemail@mydomain>
Received: from pure.maildistiller.com (unknown [10.70.45.17])
    by dispatch1-eu1.ppe-hosted.com (PPE Hosted ESMTP Server) with ESMTP id 1578A20052
    for <user@domain>; Fri, 18 Sep 2020 11:50:00 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from eu1-mdac16-8.fra.mdlocal (unknown [10.70.45.28])
    by pure.maildistiller.com (PPE Hosted ESMTP Server) with ESMTP id 13BD18009B
    for <user@domain>; Fri, 18 Sep 2020 11:50:00 +0000 (UTC)
X-Virus-Scanned: Proofpoint Essentials engine
Received: from mx1-eu1.ppe-hosted.com (unknown [10.70.45.116])
    by pure.maildistiller.com (PPE Hosted ESMTP Server) with ESMTPS id 583DC4005A
    for <user@domain>; Fri, 18 Sep 2020 11:49:59 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from mydomain (my.domain [my ip])
    by mx1-eu1.ppe-hosted.com (PPE Hosted ESMTP Server) with ESMTP id 75F9CB80064
    for <user@domain>; Fri, 18 Sep 2020 11:49:39 +0000 (UTC)
From: <myemail@mydomain>
To: <user@domain>
Subject: This is a test message that hopefully passes DMARC
Date: Fri, 18 Sep 2020 12:12:00 -0000
X-MDID: 1600429799-WQVTD-u02kSV
X-PPE-DISP: 1600429799;WQVTD-u02kSV
```

Spambrella requires that all destination servers use port 25. I have been testing using port 25.

I can post my Postfix configuration files if requested, Stack Exchange flagged them as spam when I tried to append them to this post.

If anyone can help me resolve this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a1.mail.domain.localhost?

Comment: I'm not sure, its the mail subdomain I'm trying to configure, with 'a1' prepended, and 'localhost' appended. I think it might be a relay host that's been set up by Spambrella, but the [IP] is the correct static IP of my machine.